# Dynamic Url Rewriting additional questions

Tags: url, url-rewriting, reroute

After reading several articles about URL rewrite with aspnet on this forum I still have some unanswered questions.
I understand the concept but haven't seen examples of functionality I like to have.
Hope someone can help me out with:

1. dynamically add new rules
   when I add new record in database a new rewrite URL needs to be created.
   for example a record with name of a city has to redirect request to city.aspx?cityId=1

URL: http://example.com/rotterdam/
shows: http://example.com/city.aspx?cityID=1

what is a good way to save theses rules? (xml file  or load in memory)
what is best way to handle requests : global.asax or HTTP module?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ASP.net are you targeting?

Version 3.5 and above you can utilise Routing  (even with webforms) below that you can't :)

Assuming that you can use routes, you can do the following in the global asax...

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add(new Route("/cities/{cityname}",new CityRouteHandler()));
}

where cityroutehandler is like the customroutehandler described in the answer here

[Friendly URLs for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340/friendly-urls-for-asp-net)